# Uninitialized constant error in controller#create

Tags: ruby-on-rails, controller, nameerror, uninitialized-constant

I am trying to make a form and submit a skill and description into a database.  I am almost done however I am getting this error after submitting my info:

```
NameError in SkillsController#create
uninitialized constant Skill::Description
```

and it points to this action in my controller:

```
def create
  @skills = Skill.new(skill_params)
  if @skills.save
    redirect_to :action => 'index'
  else
    @skills = Skill.find(:all)
    render :action => 'new'
  end
end
```

I have a private method at the bottom defining params which states:

```
private

  def skill_params
  params.require(:skill).permit(:description)
  end
```

I hope this is enough info to find the issue and I will post my form and skill.rb if anyone thinks that will help.  Thanks stackers and good luck! I will keep looking into the error and really appreciate any help on the matter.

---

This is the fullstack trace as requested:

```
activerecord (4.1.2.rc1) lib/active_record/inheritance.rb:133:in `compute_type'
activerecord (4.1.2.rc1) lib/active_record/reflection.rb:221:in `klass'
activerecord (4.1.2.rc1) lib/active_record/associations/association.rb:214:in `raise_on_type_mismatch!'
activerecord (4.1.2.rc1) lib/active_record/associations/collection_association.rb:356:in `block in replace'
activerecord (4.1.2.rc1) lib/active_record/associations/collection_association.rb:356:in `each_char'
activerecord (4.1.2.rc1) lib/active_record/associations/collection_association.rb:356:in `replace'
activerecord (4.1.2.rc1) lib/active_record/associations/collection_association.rb:41:in `writer'
activerecord (4.1.2.rc1) lib/active_record/associations/builder/association.rb:118:in `description='
activerecord (4.1.2.rc1) lib/active_record/attribute_assignment.rb:45:in `public_send'
activerecord (4.1.2.rc1) lib/active_record/attribute_assignment.rb:45:in `_assign_attribute'
activerecord (4.1.2.rc1) lib/active_record/attribute_assignment.rb:32:in `block in assign_attributes'
activerecord (4.1.2.rc1) lib/active_record/attribute_assignment.rb:26:in `each'
activerecord (4.1.2.rc1) lib/active_record/attribute_assignment.rb:26:in `assign_attributes'
activerecord (4.1.2.rc1) lib/active_record/core.rb:455:in `init_attributes'
activerecord (4.1.2.rc1) lib/active_record/core.rb:198:in `initialize'
activerecord (4.1.2.rc1) lib/active_record/inheritance.rb:30:in `new'
activerecord (4.1.2.rc1) lib/active_record/inheritance.rb:30:in `new'
app/controllers/skills_controller.rb:29:in `create'
actionpack (4.1.2.rc1) lib/action_controller/metal/implicit_render.rb:4:in `send_action'
actionpack (4.1.2.rc1) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:189:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.1.2.rc1) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:10:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.1.2.rc1) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:20:in `block in process_action'
activesupport (4.1.2.rc1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:113:in `call'
activesupport (4.1.2.rc1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:113:in `call'
activesupport (4.1.2.rc1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:229:in `block in halting'
activesupport (4.1.2.rc1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:229:in `call'
activesupport (4.1.2.rc1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:229:in `block in halting'
activesupport (4.1.2.rc1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:166:in `call'
activesupport (4.1.2.rc1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:166:in `block in halting'
activesupport (4.1.2.rc1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:166:in `call'
activesupport (4.1.2.rc1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:166:in `block in halting'
activesupport (4.1.2.rc1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:166:in `call'
activesupport (4.1.2.rc1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:166:in `block in halting'
activesupport (4.1.2.rc1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:86:in `call'
activesupport (4.1.2.rc1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:86:in `run_callbacks'
actionpack (4.1.2.rc1) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:19:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.1.2.rc1) lib/action_controller/metal/rescue.rb:29:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.1.2.rc1) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:31:in `block in process_action'
activesupport (4.1.2.rc1) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:159:in `block in instrument'
activesupport (4.1.2.rc1) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
activesupport (4.1.2.rc1) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:159:in `instrument'
actionpack (4.1.2.rc1) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:30:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.1.2.rc1) lib/action_controller/metal/params_wrapper.rb:250:in `process_action'
activerecord (4.1.2.rc1) lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:18:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.1.2.rc1) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:136:in `process'
actionview (4.1.2.rc1) lib/action_view/rendering.rb:30:in `process'
actionpack (4.1.2.rc1) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:196:in `dispatch'
actionpack (4.1.2.rc1) lib/action_controller/metal/rack_delegation.rb:13:in `dispatch'
actionpack (4.1.2.rc1) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:232:in `block in action'
actionpack (4.1.2.rc1) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:82:in `call'
actionpack (4.1.2.rc1) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:82:in `dispatch'
actionpack (4.1.2.rc1) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:50:in `call'
actionpack (4.1.2.rc1) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:71:in `block in call'
actionpack (4.1.2.rc1) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:59:in `each'
actionpack (4.1.2.rc1) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:59:in `call'
actionpack (4.1.2.rc1) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:678:in `call'
warden (1.2.3) lib/warden/manager.rb:35:in `block in call'
warden (1.2.3) lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in `catch'
warden (1.2.3) lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/etag.rb:23:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/conditionalget.rb:35:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/head.rb:11:in `call'
actionpack (4.1.2.rc1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/params_parser.rb:27:in `call'
actionpack (4.1.2.rc1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/flash.rb:254:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:225:in `context'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:220:in `call'
actionpack (4.1.2.rc1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:560:in `call'
activerecord (4.1.2.rc1) lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:36:in `call'
activerecord (4.1.2.rc1) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:621:in `call'
activerecord (4.1.2.rc1) lib/active_record/migration.rb:380:in `call'
actionpack (4.1.2.rc1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:29:in `block in call'
activesupport (4.1.2.rc1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:82:in `run_callbacks'
actionpack (4.1.2.rc1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:27:in `call'
actionpack (4.1.2.rc1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/reloader.rb:73:in `call'
actionpack (4.1.2.rc1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:76:in `call'
actionpack (4.1.2.rc1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:17:in `call'
actionpack (4.1.2.rc1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:30:in `call'
railties (4.1.2.rc1) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:38:in `call_app'
railties (4.1.2.rc1) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `block in call'
activesupport (4.1.2.rc1) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `block in tagged'
activesupport (4.1.2.rc1) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:26:in `tagged'
activesupport (4.1.2.rc1) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `tagged'
railties (4.1.2.rc1) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `call'
actionpack (4.1.2.rc1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:21:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:21:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in `call'
activesupport (4.1.2.rc1) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache_middleware.rb:26:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
actionpack (4.1.2.rc1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:64:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/sendfile.rb:112:in `call'
railties (4.1.2.rc1) lib/rails/engine.rb:514:in `call'
```

railties (4.1.2.rc1) lib/rails/application.rb:144:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in`call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/content_length.rb:14:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:60:in`service'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:138:in `service'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:94:in`run'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/server.rb:295:in `block in start_thread'

and this is my schema:

create_table "skills", force: true do |t|
    t.datetime "created_at"
  end

I am guessing I need to do "rails generate" and I will look into doing that next to add description into the schema.  Thanks everyone again, I know I am close to solving this.

---

I ran "rails generate migration AddDescriptionToSkills description:string" and "rake db:migrate" and I got the schema.rb updated:

```
  create_table "skills", force: true do |t|
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.string   "description"
  end
```

but I am still getting the same error.  Once again thanks everyone and I will keep you updated.

Comment: Can we see the `skills` database table description in your `schema.rb` file?

Comment: Can you give us the full stacktrace (not just the error)? that will give the actual line of code that is causing the error.

Comment: is desciption field is present in the skills table?

Comment: I will post all above, thanks for looking into this with me.